# Динамическая загрузка *.so *.dll библиотек написанных на c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Возможно ли? Я не могу понять как можно загрузить класс? Если статически слинковать заголовок и библиотеку, то можно пользоваться классами и функциями. А если динамически загрузить? Ну через dlopen или LoadLibrary.

Comment: Ручная динамическая загрузка библиотек позволяет использовать в них только С интерфейсы.

Comment: @VTT проблема блин.

Comment: @xverizex посмотрите в самом начале книги Дональда Бокса "Сущность технологии COM".

Comment: Экспортируйте из dll функцию, которая возвращает указатель / умный указатель или  ссылку на интерфейс (абстрактный класс).

Comment: @Chorkov я пользователь линукс, о windows мало что знаю. Не давно научился для windows в линукс собирать приложения. Поэтому и задумался, стоит ли программу на c++ писать, или же на си лучше. Как экспортировать из dll такую функцию? Думаю это и для линукс пойдёт!

Comment: @xverizex текже как и C-ю функцию. Т.е. под windows пишем в декларации экспортируемой функции `declspec(dllexport)`, под linux ничего делать не надо. Потом смотрим манглированное имя фукнции в полученной dll/so. После загрузки берешь нужную функцию с помощью dlsym. Но это если ты собираешься грузить dll/so динамически. Статическая линковка (в случае c++, под linux) гораздо(!) проще.